# I need to make a simple quiz for School in c#

Tags: c#

first off here is the terribly written code I have mangled together:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is 9+10");
            Console.WriteLine("19");
            Console.WriteLine("21");
            Console.Read();

            if (Console.ReadLine() == "19")
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong");
```

Now my problem is no matter what is typed the program always displays "correct" message and never the "Wrong" Message even if the wrong answer is entered. Can someone please explain where I am going wrong I am really new to programming.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console.Read() reads a single character.  Console.ReadLine() reads the whole line of characters.

In this case, your Console.Read() doesn't need to be there. when you type in "19" for the answer, this is what's happening:

```
What is 9+10
19
21

19
Wrong
```

What the computer is seeing:

```
What is 9+10
19
21

(input)1
(inputLine)9
Wrong
```

It actually says "Correct" if you enter 119, as it will read the first "1" and then the rest of the line.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solved your problem!